# Warning: [W030] Some entities could not be aligned in the text

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, entity-linking

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("XYZxyzg hat die beste Camera für Selfies", {"entities": [(0, 7, "BRAND"), (23, 28, "CAMERA")]}),
]
```

Upon training this, I keep getting an error on this line that:

```
serWarning: [W030] Some entities could not be aligned in the text "XYZxyzg hat die beste Camera für Selfie" with entities "[(0, 7, 'BRAND'), (23, 28, 'CAMERA')]". Use `spacy.gold.biluo_tags_from_offsets(nlp.make_doc(text), entities)` to check the alignment. Misaligned entities ('-') will be ignored during training.
  gold = GoldParse(doc, **gold)
```

What's wrong with my indexes? Should I exclude whitespaces? I tried that too but it doesn't seem to work. How can I use `spacy.gold.biluo_tags_from_offsets(nlp.make_doc(text), entities)` to check indexes as the warning suggests?

Comment: Please [reprex]

Answer (score 2):

From your post:

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("XYZxyzg hat die beste Camera für Selfies", {"entities": [(0, 7, "BRAND"), (23, 28, "CAMERA")]}),
]
```

The entity offsets need to align to token boundaries. You can't start/end an entity in the middle of a token. In your case, it looks like a small error crept in, and I think the offsets of the second entity should be `(22, 28, "CAMERA")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`spacy.gold.biluo_tags_from_offsets` has been deprecated, I believe.

You can replace `spacy.gold import biluo_tags_from_offsets` with `spacy.training import offsets_to_biluo_tags`

https://spacy.io/api/top-level#offsets_to_biluo_tags